# Matlab Generating a Matrix

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate a matrix in matlab which I will use to solve a polynomial regression formula.

Here is how I am trying to generate the matrix:

I have an input vector X containing N elements and an integer d. d is the integer to know how many times we will add a new column to the matrix we are trying to generate int he following way.

N = [X^d X^{d-1} ... X^2 X O]

O is a vector of same length as X with all 1's.

Everytime d > 2 it does not work.

Can you see any errors in my code (i am new to matlab):

```
function [ PR ] = PolyRegress( X, Y, d )
    O = ones(length(X), 1)
    N = [X O]

    for j = 2:d
        tmp = power(X, j)
        N = [tmp N]
    end

    %TO DO: compute PR


end
```

Comment: After looking at the output again I realized I was doing it properly all along. I did not see the 1.0e+05 * before the output :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the [matlab function vander](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/vander.html) already does what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, this does do what I want. Just returns it in the reverse order. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [VANDER](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/vander.html) function will only generate powers of the vector upto `d = length(X)-1`. For a more general solution, you can use the [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) function (works with any value of `d`):

```
N = bsxfun(@power, X(:), d:-1:0)
```

Example:

```
>> X = (1:.5:2);
>> d = 5;
>> N = bsxfun(@power, X(:), d:-1:0)
N =
            1            1            1            1            1            1
       7.5938       5.0625        3.375         2.25          1.5            1
           32           16            8            4            2            1
```

I'm not sure if this is the order you want, but it can be easily reversed: use `0:d` instead of `d:-1:0`...