# Matlab for loop changing each row & column

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix to look like this:

```
[1 x x^2 x^3 x^4 x^5]
[1 y y^2 y^3 y^4 y^5]
[1 z z^2 z^3 z^4 z^5]
```

and so on.  The matrix which is going to have my base vales of x,y,z,k etc is `Orig`:

```
Orig = [ x y z k];
```

and my starting matrix is going to be

```
A = [1 x x^2 x^3 x^4 x^5];
```

My next line of code is

```
for i=(2:10)
    A(i)=A(i)^A(:,i)
end
```

This for loop correctly changes the power that each row needs to be raised too, however it will not go to the next value in my `Orig` matrix.

So basically, I need to tell Matlab a way, within the for loop, to stop using `Orig(1,1)` and go to `Orig(1,2)` for row 2.

Comment: similar question: [Matlab Generating a Matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7547080/97160)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with a double loop

```
Orig = [x y z k];
exponent = [0 1 2 3 4 5];

%# preassign output to speed up loop
output = zeros(length(Orig),length(exponent));

%# loop over all elements in Orig
for r = 1:length(Orig)
%# loop over all exponents
for c = 1:length(exponent)
output(r,c) = Orig(r)^exponent(c);
end
end
```

However, this is not the way you'd normally program this in Matlab.

Instead, you'd replicate both `Orig` and `exponent`, and do the calculation in one, vectorized operation:

```
%# transpose orig so that it is a n-by-1 array
repOrig = repmat(Orig',1,length(exponent); %'#
repExp  = repmat(exponent,length(Orig),1);
%# perform the exponent operation in one go
output = repOrig .^ repExp; %# note the ".", it applies operations element-wise
```

Since a few years, there has been a shortcut version for this, using the function [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html). This will automatically perform the expansion we did above with `repmat`, and it will be faster.

```
output = bsxfun(@power, Orig', exponent);
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
n = 5;
OrigArranged = Orig'*ones(1,n);
PowerMat = ones(length(Orig),1) * [1:n];
A = OrigArranged.^PowerMat;
```

I will test it once Octave is installed, but it should work.

edit: I've corrected minor mistakes, now it works